# No module named pcapy pyinstaller

Tags: python, pcap, pyinstaller, scapy

This is my first time using `pyinstaller` and after I build my executable and try to run my executable I get `ImportError: No module named pcapy`.  Can someone tell me why the module might be missing?  Not sure if it helps but my script is 1 file and here are all my imports:

```
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

import subprocess
import threading
import os

import sys
from scapy.all import *
import logging
```

I'm running OS X 10.10.5, scapy 2.3.1 and python 2.7.9

Comment: Adding os and scapy version (2.x or 3.x at least) would help

Comment: Try adding the argument `--hidden-import=pcapy` when building the application.

Comment: @Yoel I just tried `pyinstaller client-ws-server.py --hidden-import=pcapy` but still no luck

Comment: @EriksDobelis - I updated my original post with the version info.

Comment: @DanRamos, how are your debugging efforts going? Have you isolated the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `hook-pcap.py` with the following content:

```py
import os
import glob
import itertools

try:
    # PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES is unavailable in older versions
    from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
except ImportError:
    try:
        from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES as PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
    except ImportError:
        import imp
        PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES = set([f[0] for f in imp.get_suffixes()
                                     if f[2] == imp.C_EXTENSION])

def hook(mod):
    module_directory = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
    bundled = []

    for libname, ext in itertools.product(('pcap', ),
                                          PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES):
        bundled.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(module_directory, libname + ext)))

    for f in bundled:
        name = os.path.join('pcap', os.path.basename(f))
        if hasattr(mod, 'pyinstaller_binaries'):
            mod.pyinstaller_binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))
        else: # mod.pyinstaller_binaries is unavailable in older versions
            mod.binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))

    return mod
```

Repeat the process with `hook-dnet.py`:

```py
import os
import glob
import itertools

try:
    # PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES is unavailable in older versions
    from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
except ImportError:
    try:
        from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES as PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
    except ImportError:
        import imp
        PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES = set([f[0] for f in imp.get_suffixes()
                                     if f[2] == imp.C_EXTENSION])

def hook(mod):
    module_directory = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
    bundled = []

    for libname, ext in itertools.product(('dnet', ),
                                          PY_EXTENSION_SUFFIXES):
        bundled.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(module_directory, libname + ext)))

    for f in bundled:
        name = os.path.join('dnet', os.path.basename(f))
        if hasattr(mod, 'pyinstaller_binaries'):
            mod.pyinstaller_binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))
        else: # mod.pyinstaller_binaries is unavailable in older versions
            mod.binaries.append((name, f, 'BINARY'))

    return mod
```

When building, specify `pcap` and `dnet` as hidden imports and supply the path to the directory in which you placed the hook files as a value to the `--additional-hooks-dir` argument, as follows:

```
--hidden-import=pcap --hidden-import=dnet --additional-hooks-dir=<path_to_directory_of_hook_files>
```

Comment: I ran the following : `pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=/Users/dan/Desktop/app  client-ws-server.py` .  After that I `cd`ed into dist/client/ws-server and ran `./client-ws-server` and still get the same import error.

Comment: Try building with the argument `--log-level=debug` and check whether anything is written about importing _pcapy_. Also, when executing the application, add the [`-v` flag for verbose import messages‌​](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#getting-python-s-verbose-imports).

Comment: Searched through the 545 lines of output and didn't see any reference to pcapy

Comment: Can you join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85227/pyinstaller)?

Comment: Still having some issues with this, any chance you could assist me again ?

Comment: Sure, I might be available for chat during the weekend. Meanwhile, have you isolated the problematic piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem, when I want to use pyinstaller to convert a python script, which use pcapy module directly, to a executable. And below is my solution.

Enter the python module directory, where is Lib/site-packages in Windows. And I found that the pcapy module existed as a single file, named 'pcapy-0.10.9-py2.7-win-amd64.egg'. I thought it may be some compress technique, and pyinstaller was unable to analysis this compressed file in that time. So I extract the 'pcapy-0.10.9-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', and delete the original 'pcapy-0.10.9-py2.7-win-amd64.egg' file, rename the extracted directory to 'pcapy-0.10.9-py2.7-win-amd64.egg'.

Then, I converted the script again, and this time, the executable worked right, no any import error.